# Linq equivalient to JavaScript's join?

Tags: c#, linq

In JavaScript if I have var `arr = ["a", "b", "c"]` I can say `arr.join(',');` to get a string containing the comma-delimited list of values.  Is there a direct way to do this in Linq?

I know I can use `Aggregate` ie  `pluginNames.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " + s2);`  But that seems a bit clunky.   Is there something cleaner?  Something hypothetically like

```
pluginNames.JavaScriptJoin(", ");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
string.Join(", ", pluginNames);
```

Answer (score 14):

Just use `String.Join` - not part of LINQ, just of the framework:

```
string joined = string.Join(", ", array);
```

If that's *really* too clunky for you, you can write an extension method:

```
public static string JoinStrings(this string[] bits, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, bits);
}
```

Note that .NET 4 has more overloads for `string.Join`, including taking sequences (rather than just arrays) and not just of strings.

I would suggest that you *don't* just use the name `Join`, as that will look like you're doing an inner join.

Comment: No no, not too clunky at all -- string.join will work fine.  I wonder what the new devs at my old job are thinking looking at all those silly calls to `Aggregate()` :)

Comment: I see you're already capped; sorry those +8 didn't do much for you - Hope you're not miffed I gave the check to the lower-rep guy :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `string.Join()`:

```
string result = string.Join(",", pluginNames);
```